# Invalid column name in DB2

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I'm having trouble with the column name of one of my tables.

My version of DB2 is DB2/LINUXX8664 11.1.0. I'm running it on a CentOS Linux Release 7.2.1511. My version of IBM Data Studio is 4.1.2.

The column is named "NRO_AÑO" in the table "PERIODO" in the schema "COMPRAS".

When I execute the simple query

```
SELECT NRO_AÑO
FROM COMPRAS.PERIODO
```

it yields the following error:

```
"NRO_AÑO" is not valid in the context where it is used.. SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, DRIVER=3.68.61
```

If I execute the query

```
SELECT *
FROM COMPRAS.PERIODO
```

it yields data with the following columns

[image]

I'm guessing it has something to do with the charsets involved, but I'm not sure where to look at.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try this query: `SELECT "NRO_AÑO" FROM COMPRAS.PERIODO` ?  Maybe escaping the column name will get around the special character problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen same -206 error.

Comment: It looks like an encoding problem, but I don't know enough about DB2 to be of further help.

Comment: What's the database code page? `SELECT VALUE FROM SYSIBMADM.DBCFG WHERE NAME = 'codepage'`. What's the locale setting in your Linux session? Did you choose the same locale when installing Data Studio, or is it the default `en_US`?

Comment: The codepage value is 1208. The linux locale is es_AR.utf8. I didn't install Data Studio and I'm not sure how to check the locale that was used.

Comment: Based on your other comment, it looks like something wrong happened when the table was created. Check what `db2 describe table compras.periodo` returns and what is the table DDL statement (`db2look -d yourdb -z compras -t periodo -e`). May be you will need to re-create the table.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me:

```
[db2inst1@server ~]$ db2 "create table compras.periodo (nro_año int)"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
[db2inst1@server ~]$ db2 "insert into compras.periodo values (1)"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
[db2inst1@server ~]$ db2 "insert into compras.periodo (nro_año) values (2)"
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
[db2inst1@server ~]$ db2 "select nro_año from compras.periodo"

NRO_AÑO
-----------
          1
          2

  2 record(s) selected.
```

Probably, you are having a console encoding problem (putty), and you should review how the name of the column in the database is stored:

```
db2 "select colname from syscat.columns where tabname = 'PERIODO'"

COLNAME                                                                                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NRO_AÑO                                                                                                         

  1 record(s) selected.
```

Creating the table from Putty (SSH client) and then selecting from Data Studio, then the characters higher that 128 will have different representations. Java (DataStudio) uses UTF-8, but probably the script used to create the table used another encoding and this is having problems in the database (Putty, Windows, Notepad, etc).

Comment: Curiously, the column name in syscat.columns is NULL!

Comment: The table structure including the column names.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I run the script from DB2 command line processor on DB2 9.7.

```
db2 => CREATE TABLE TEMP_TABLE(NRO_AÑO INTEGER)
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
db2 => INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE(NRO_AÑO) VALUES(1)
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
db2 => SELECT * FROM TEMP_TABLE

NRO_AÑO
-----------
   1

1 record(s) selected.

db2 => select colname from syscat.columns where tabname = 'TEMP_TABLE'

COLNAME
------------
NRO_AÑO

  1 record(s) selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue may also be that columns need to be enclosed in quotes, as found in IBM Data Studio Ver 4, example:

INSERT INTO DB2ADMIN.FB_WEB_POSTS ("UserName","FaceID", "FaceURL","FaceStory","FaceMessage","FaceDate","FaceStamp")

VALUES ('SocialMate','233555900032117_912837012103999', 'http://localhost/doculogs.nsf/index.html', 'Some Message or Story','Random Files Project for Lotus Notes, Google, Oracle App samples', '2017-09-09', '2017-09.23');